# How to update using Angular (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, angularjs, http, laravel-5

**PROBLEM**

I'm trying to update a list name using Angular. Which method do I need to use? PUT? At the moment when I do PUT it shows a 405 error Method not allowed, so what am I doing wrong?

**MY CODE**

Angular

```
$scope.updatel = function($event){
    console.log($event.keyCode);
    if ($event.keyCode == 13) {
        var list = {
            name: $scope.editlist
        };
        $scope.editlist = '';
        $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: 'http://localhost/anydo/anydocopy/anydocopy/public/lists/1',
            data: list
        })
            .success(function () {
                console.log('true');
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost/anydocopy/public/lists'
                })
                    .success(function (d) {
                        console.log(d);
                        $scope.listsdata = d;
                    });
            })
            .error(function () {
                console.log('false');
            });
}};
```

Laravel route

```
Route::put('lists/{id}', 'ListsController@update');
```

Laravel controller

```
public function update($id, CreateListsRequest $request)
{
    $response['lists'] = Lists::findorfail($id)->update($request->all());

    return Response($response, 201);
}
```

Laravel middleware

```
class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set(
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
            'Authorization, Content-Type, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, x-xsrf-token, X-Requested-With'
        );
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="edit" ng-model="editlist" ng-show="edbut.show" ng-keydown="updatel($event)" onkeydown="hideshow(document.getElementById('edit'))" class="form-control" style="font:24px bold;" value="{{lists.name}}" />
```

**EDITED**

Now I have working URL, yep it was wrong. At the moment PUT method still doesn't work and shows 500 Internal Server Error. What is wrong? Seems like the error is with `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:`

Answer (score 0):

The `methodNotAllowed` exception indicates that a route doesn't exist for the HTTP method you are requesting.

The URL for which you are making PUT request and the route that you are using don't map with each other.

```
url: 'http://localhost/anydocopy/public/lists/1'

Route::put('lists/{id}', 'ListsController@update');
```

Why don't you add a debug point to the route and see if it is getting picked ?

Comment: And also i actually don't know how to add that debug point.. I'm new at laravel :D

Comment: Check error logs  with :  tail -f storage/logs/laravel-2015-09-2.log
on your project root . Check why its giving 500 error.  (Assuming you are using laravel 5)

Comment: Also there is problem that i can't read editlists text input.. idk why.. im trying to get value in console, but it's get undefined. So that could be the problem why error appiers?

Comment: I think I found why is error.. `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:`
So what to do with this?

Comment: I have working deleting and also i can create new list.. So why is there problem with update? Where I lose token?

Comment: Try cleaning the cache.
To clear the cache use :php artisan cache:clear

Comment: There are more than 4 questions on stackoverflow itself for the same error. There are many ways of getting this error. So try out the solutions on these questions.